# What's the meaning of なんや in the end of sentence?

Tags: translation, particles, learning

Here's the full sentence.

うちっちーの中にはグロスやらなんや

What does なんや mean? Also, about particle "やら", does "グロスやら" means "lip gloss and things like that" or does it denote uncertainty about the gloss?

Here's the link for the context. https://twitter.com/Saito_Shuka/status/903899104664731652

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> うちっちーの中にはグロスやらなんや

Befor examining the given sentence, let's study the following phrases.

> (1) 　なんやらかんやら (なんやら-かんやら)
>   (1)'　何｛なん｝やら彼｛かん｝やら (何｛なん｝やら-彼｛かん｝やら)
>   (2) 　**なんやかんや (なんや-かんや)**
>   (2)'　何｛なん｝や彼｛かん｝や (何｛なん｝や-彼｛かん｝や)
>   (3) 　なんだかんだ (なんだ-かんだ)
>   (3)'　何｛なん｝だ彼｛かん｝だ (何｛なん｝だ-彼｛かん｝だ)
>   (4) 　なんだかだ (なんだ-かだ)
>   (4)'　何｛なん｝だ彼｛か｝だ (何｛なん｝だ-彼｛か｝だ)

Note: We usually don't insert a dash/hyphen like that in the parenthesis. I only place it to tell you to pronounce the phrase with making a short pause at the dash is placed for your convenience.

These phrases all has the same meaning like *something or other*; *one thing or another*; *this or that*.

> does "グロスやら" means "lip gloss and things like that"?

Your understanding is correct.

I think the writer wanted to say like:

> "There are various things like a lip gloss and the like in the うちっちー pouch".
>   うちっちーの中にはグロスやら **、** なんや **かんや入｛はい｝ってます！**

やら in グロス**やら** comes from the usage of やら in "(1) なん**やら**かん**やら**" that means like "and the like". So I said your understanding is correct.

And なんや in グロスやら**なんや** comes from "(2) **なんや**かんや" by omitting かんや.

I think グロスやらなんやかんや is more formally natural than グロスやらなんや, but the writer chose グロスやらなんや because she thought the formal expression sounds or looks a little tedious.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not used to informal Japanese yet, so things like this are hard to understand. Thanks! Your explanation is easy to understand!